# Simple XML parsing error

Tags: xml, simplexml, php

I'm trying to iterate through a Twitter XML File, where the container tag is `<users>`, and each user is `<user>`. I need to create a variable `$id` based on the XML attribute `<id>` for each user.

Username is already instantiated.

```
$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends/$username.xml";
$xmlpure = file_get_contents($url);
$listxml = simplexml_load_string($xmlpure);

foreach($listxml->users->children() as $child)
  {
 $id  = $child->{"id"};
//Do another action
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in /home/.../bonus.php on line 32

Line 32 is the foreach statement, and I don't actually USE the `main()` method.

Comment: SimpleXML ignores root tag so you should not walk the tree from "users". You can do either $listxml->user or $listxml->children().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the node represented by `$child` does *not* have an `<id/>` child. You can check that out using isset() or even by outputing the node's XML with `echo $child->asXML();`

Also, if you intent to use `$id` as a string, you should cast it as such.

```
$id = (string) $child->id;
```

Another thing, you could load the document like this:

```
$listxml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Finally, when asking a question here, please always link to a relevant sample of the original XML document.

---

**Update**

As suspected, you just don't access the right nodes. If you specify the name of an inexistent node ("users" in your example) SimpleXML creates some kind of a temporary phantom node instead of generating an error. This is to allow creating new nodes more easily I believe.

Anyway, here's what your script should look like:

```
$users = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($users->user as $user)
{
    $id = (string) $user->id;
}
```

Always name your PHP vars according to the node they represent so that you always know where you are in the tree; it will save you a lot of future similar troubles. The root node is `<users/>` therefore the variable is `$users` and same for `<user/>`/`$user`.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Here is a sample XML file: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends/randomuser.xml

Is there a difference between the $child->id syntax and the $child->{"id"} syntax?

Comment: No, there's no functional difference between the two syntaxes, which is why I prefer the simpler one ;)